# Why is usePage().url returning ComputedRefImpl?

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I have the following vue page:

```
<template>
<a :class="isCurrent($page.url)"
</template>

<script setup>
import {usePage} from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'

const isCurrent = (url) => {
  console.log(url);
  console.log(usePage().url);
};
</script>
```

The url of the page is `/comment` and if I inspect the page I find exactly that: [image]

However, on the console log, the url is not displayed correctly:

[image]

While I can access the page correctly inside the template section using `$page.url` I cant access it within `<script setup>` `usePage()` creates a document where everything is ComputedRefImpl:

[image]

How can I access the page object using `usePage()` without having to pass `$page` from the template section?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.value`, similiar as with ref https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref

```
<script setup>
import {usePage} from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'

const isCurrent = (url) => {
  console.log(url);
  console.log(usePage().url.value);
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the page `props` `ref` before accessing `url`.

```js
usePage().props.value.url
```